# OpenCV Gives an error when using the imgproc functions (2)

Tags: c++, opencv

Every time I use the image processing functions in opencv, I get a c++ runtime error.

This is my code, and I get "the application has requested to terminate it in an unusual way"

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <string>

int main() {
    cv::Mat a = cv::imread("img.jpg");
    cv::Mat b(a);

    cv::Canny(a,b,250,300);
    cv::namedWindow("Hello");
    cv::imshow("Hello",b);
    cv::waitKey(2000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the libs with cmake?

Comment: Can you also post your OS (I'm assuming Windows, but just to be sure) and build environment?

Comment: The init `b(a)` is completely useless. You can safely write `Mat b`;

Answer (score 2):

The `cv::Canny` function requires always a grayscale image as input. You need to convert `a` to grayscale first. The following code snippet does the trick:

```
cv::cvtColor(a, a, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Comment: Or you could force your program to read an grayscale image (if you didn't need the colour version later on) by using `cv::imread("img.jpg", 0);` See [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread) for the details of cv::imread()

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what 'a' is after the imread?

What if it fails because the "img.jpg" is in a different directory or you don't have permission.

Comment: @tomelse He means you should add `if (a.empty()) /* print error */`